# How to line up data in a UITableView cell?

Tags: xcode4, uitableview

I have this UITableView (http://imgur.com/3YQzm) that I want to list 3 textfields on each row.  The info is stored on a SQLite d/b.  The first row I need for titles.

How can I list the info in each row so it looks "nice" (i.e. lined up in columns)?  Do I need a custom cell for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I know, you have to put the labels in the specific locations, so you have to define the coordenates for a nice look. I don't know if you are using a xib file for the cell, but, for this case, is better to use it. In the xib will be easy to set the correct location for your labels.

Comment: Hi Luis... no, not using XIB, using Storyboard... any examples/docs you can think of where coordinates are programmatically set for cells?

Comment: You can check this apple sample code http://goo.gl/ThQGO, but instead of configure the cell layout by code, create a XIB, make the layout in the xib, then load the xib programmaticaly in the cell. You can find more information here http://ijoshsmith.com/2011/07/16/creating-a-custom-uitableviewcell-in-ios-4/ and http://www.atelierdumobile.com/blog/2011/03/24/loading-custom-uitableviewcells-from-xib-files-yet-another-method/

Comment: Can I use XIB's with Storyboard?  I didn't find anything on Google

Comment: yes, you can create xib for a custon UITableViewCell, and then load it with a method called loadWithNib. You will not have any problem with storyboard, because you will not using the xib for a main view in the window, just for a cell in the table.

Comment: Thanks Luis... do you have an example or doc that would give me more detail?

Comment: I love this site http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/03/load-from-nib-or-construct-views-in.html , if was useful, remember to give me a vote! XD

Comment: Here in the answer , at the top of number '0'. The up arrow for +1 vote, the down arrow for a -1 vote.